# Selenium not opening a webpage

Tags: python, macos, selenium

When I run the following code, I get an error that I'm not understanding, and I think it has something to do with the way I've set up selenium on my computer. (I'm on Mac OS if it's relevant)

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
driver.close()
```

I get the following Error when I try to run that program:

```
File "win.py", line 3, in <module> 
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
File "/Users/shazam/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 64, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
File "/Users/shazam/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 51, in __init__ 
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
File "/Users/shazam/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 69, in launch_browser 
    self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)
File "/Users/shazam/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 92, in _start_from_profile_path 
    env=self._firefox_env)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__ 
    errread, errwrite) 
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
```

Comment: Hi Derek, check this if it helps - [Stack-17580730](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580730)

Comment: No, it was even better than that. You have to have firefox installed in order to run the Firefox version of Selenium. I will find a box of shame for myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error, was because Firefox was not installed on my computer. Something that should have been obvious to me, but wasn't.