# Selenium error with Firefox: does firefox need to be in applications folder?

Tags: python-2.7, firefox, selenium

I'd like to use selenium to download a series of outputs from a web form

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

the above code gives the following error -

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 78, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 67, in launch_browser
    self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 90, in _start_from_profile_path
    env=self._firefox_env)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Firefox is currently installed on the desktop rather than in my Applications folder, could that be the cause of the problem? If so, is there a workaround that means I don't have to move it to Applications?

Comment: Try this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580730/python-selenium-error-when-trying-to-launch-firefox

Answer (score 0):

You can and probably in your case should specify the path to the firefox binary *explicitly*:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('/path/to/binary')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```