# How to excute selenium webdriver in linux without display

Tags: python, linux, selenium

I am trying to use selenium webdriver in centos to test my webpage.
But,I got an error message when I execute the process.
Can someone help me?

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display=Display(visible=0, size=(320, 240)).start()
path = "/usr/bin/firefox"
driver= webdriver.Firefox(path)
driver.get("www.google.com")
html_source = driver.page_source
print html_source
driver.close()
```

And here is the error message:

```
File "/var/www/test/test.py", line 19, in <module>
driver= webdriver.Firefox(path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 54, in __init__
self.NATIVE_EVENTS_ALLOWED and self.profile.native_events_enabled)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'native_events_enabled'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure your problem has to do with the fact that your trying to pass the path to your firefox binary as a string, instead as a "FirefoxBinary" object, furthermore the first argument to Firefox() is a FirefoxProfile(). Doing the following should resolve the issue.

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

display=Display(visible=0, size=(320, 240)).start()
binary = FirefoxBinary("/usr/bin/firefox") 
driver= webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
driver.get("www.google.com")
html_source = driver.page_source
print html_source
driver.close()
```

see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580730/python-selenium-error-when-trying-to-launch-firefox%22post%22) for an answer to a very similar problem.