# how to resolve this error in python webscraping?

Tags: python, selenium

I imported selenium modules in python file but when i run this code I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "koovs.py", line 4, in <module>
  browser=webdriver.Firefox()
File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
  self.service.start()
File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
  os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x0000000003228400>> ignored
```

What i have to do. My code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.koovs.com/women/dresses/sortby-discount-high/')
soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)
```

Comment: you should paste the error as text instead of image.

Comment: I think that error image is not correct for your question.

Comment: Can you confirm what OS you're on and/or VM setup? And that Firefox is installed and the executable is in your PATH? I assume you're on Windows. Maybe check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17582010/823942 to see if you leads you down the right path.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install `geckodriver`?

To use Firefox webdriver, You must install `geckodriver`. And put the binary file into folder which can be accessed by system PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [the link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and download `geckodriver` based on your `windows 32 or 64 bit`.

Extract the geckodriver.exe to your computer and add the corresponding path to Environmental variables.

**For Example:** if you extracted the geckodriver.exe to Desktop, you should add desktop path to `Path Env.` variable.

Then re-execute your code. Sometimes env. var don't reflect. In this case, you might need to restart your IDE (like Eclipse).

Hope it helps.