# Python Selenium Firefox Profile Missing error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to make a Firefox driver using Selenium. However, I am having trouble creating the driver in the first place.

I try to make it like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Running this opens a warning window saying: "Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible."

Then the following error is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 162, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status: 1
```

---

I have tried several solutions, including:

- I placed the geckodriver in the PATH
- Typing out the path name (`driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile="default")`)
- Specifying the profile path (as in the answer on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/Q8CpIFiZcBk)
- Creating a new Firefox profile and attempting that path instead

---

I am using Python 3.6.4 and Firefox 58.0.1.
**Edit:**
While there are several similar questions, most of them relate either to tor, or result in a different error.

Also, I forgot to mention but I am using Debian Linux

Comment: What machine are you on?

Comment: While the error code appears to be different, the solution for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580730/python-selenium-error-when-trying-to-launch-firefox appears to have fixed the problem. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

The error does gives us some hint about whats wrong happening :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status: 1
```

While working with *Selenium v3.x* you have to download the latest *GeckoDriver* from [*mozilla/geckodriver*](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and place it in your system. While you initialize the *webdriver* and the *Web Browser* pass the argument `executable_path` along with the absolute path of the *GeckoDriver* binary and invoke the proper *url* as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver   
Base_url = "https://www.facebook.com/"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:/path/to/geckodriver.exe')    
driver.get(Base_url)
```

Additionally :

- Clean you *Project Workspace* within your IDE regularly only to build your project with required dependencies.
- Use [***CCleaner***](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe away the OS chores periodically.
- If your *Web Browser* base version is too old uninstall the *Web Browser* through [***Revo Uninstaller***](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA released version of the *Web Browser*.

Comment: Add the folder containing your geckodriver executable/binary to your system's PATH Environment Variable, Selenium 3 will find it without passing an executable path that will break the moment you run your code on another system.